# some keys don't wok on background command

Tags: asterisk

I have a dialplan like below, but it don't work correctly for these numbers: 1,2,3

when user press 0 or 4..9 i haven't problem, but it can't detect 1,2,3
only when background finished and waitexten() started it can accept 1,2,3 numbers too.

```
   exten => s,1,Answer()
   exten => s,n,Background(sherkat)
   exten => s,n,WaitExten(10)
   exten => 1,1,Goto(default,305,1)
   exten => 2,1,Goto(default,303,1)
   exten => 3,1,Goto(default,302,1)
   exten => 4,1,Goto(default,301,1)
   exten => 5,1,Goto(default,324,1)
   exten => t,1,Goto(default,304,1)
   exten => i,1,Goto(default,304,1)
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend two things.  First, add a "Wait(1)" command immediately after your Answer() to ensure that the audio stream is open to both ends properly.  Secondly, add a "_" before each extension number; eg:

```
   exten => s,1,Answer()
    same => n,Wait(1)
    same => n,Background(sherkat)
    same => n,WaitExten(10)

   exten => _1,1,Goto(default,305,1)
   exten => _2,1,Goto(default,303,1)
   exten => _3,1,Goto(default,302,1)
   exten => _4,1,Goto(default,301,1)
   exten => _5,1,Goto(default,324,1)

   exten => t,1,Goto(default,304,1)
   exten => i,1,Goto(default,304,1)
```

... try that and let me know if it works better for you.  I've found the regex qualifier "_" often improves IVR behavior/ precision.